# Text dissapearing of Text Field when view.endEditing(true) iOS (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

my problem is the following, I don't know if is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong. The thing is that I have a view as shown below, and have two text field (the third one was for testing purposes), but I only can see the text if I have the UITextField focused, once I tap anywhere else but the TextFields view.endEditing(true) is executed. and then the text is not gone, but not visible either. There is text in the second and third textField. ¿Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: *Added code for better comprenhension.*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fondo_nadserv")!)

    otroDatoField.delegate = self
    datoField.delegate = self

    //Looks for single or multiple taps.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func DismissKeyboard(){
    view.endEditing(true)
}}
```

[image: There is text in two of the three fields]

Comment: This is not normal behavior. Could you post your `touchesBegan` method with your `view.endEditing()` code?

Comment: I edited the question so you can see the methods I'm using for dismiss the keyboard. I'm not using `touchesBegan`.